# SQL Server: Sum() and other mathematical functions

Tags: sql-server

```
  playerID     differential  
----------------------------
5              10.62                  
5              18.55          
5              0.96             
4              1.13             
5              5.56       
4              1.12 
5              3.45
```

I am trying to take the sum of the 5 most recent values with the same playerID, then divide that total by the number of different differentials taken, in this case 5.

I a completely lost as I am a beginner in SQL, I know I can do the sum of the values using the sum() function but I am not sure how only grab the most recent values, or how to send that value to a different table after the operation has been completed.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there timestamp or auto id field to indicate latest record?

Comment: No their is no timestamp but their is an auto increment ID field that is just called ID.

Comment: are you using sql server 2012 or above ?then the query can be very short.

Answer (score 2):

You can use window analytic function row number to partition the rows based on player id order by id

You can then get recent 5 records sum for each playerid

```
 With CTE 
 As
 (
     Select id, playerid, differential,
     row_number() over ( partition by playerid order by id desc) as rn
 )
 Select playerid, sum(differential)/5 as total
 From CTE 
 Where rn<=5
 Group by playerid
```

Comment: Wait what is the "With CTE"?

Comment: It is common table expression, it is similar to having it as subquery but more readable

Comment: This is the correct answer although it occurs to me that SUM(differential)/5 is the same as AVG(differential).